# Cassandra installation issues

Tags: cassandra, installation, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to install datastax's cassandra in ubuntu, I can't understand the installation process. Help me.

steps followed :
 jdk installation

cassandra download by command

```
curl -L http://downloads.datastax.com/datastax-ddc/datastax-ddc-3.5.0-bin.tar.gz | tar xz
```

That is all, I can't understand what or any of the installation steps, provided [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/install/installTarball.html#installTarball__single-node-start).
BTW What is it meant by "*install_location"* and *"path_to_install"* 
.

Answer (score 0):

install_location is the directory you want to untar the files you have downloaded in. I think path_to_install is the same thing (but I cant find it on your link)

These are very basic things your having problems with. You might find its easier to install the packaged install via apt (http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/install/installDeb.html). It will install everything in standard locations (http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/install/referenceInstallLocatePkg.html), set up paths, users, env variables etc..

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i am unable to follow the instructions, what should i do to master these things. BTW I get this message when i run curl -L command    rl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

Comment: Arun - that sounds like its something to do with your specific server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Johnny, I will figure it out. I have been trying from a week to install. Its a nightmare. What should I do to master these things. ,Would learning bash help?. or what should I do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arun - if your going to be deploying this into production and looking after it, I would certainly advise understanding Linux. If your just trying to install it learn how to develop using there are installers for Windows and OSx that might be easier. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @Jonny M